# I want to format my date as its coming in MM/dd/yyyyTHH:MM:SS in Angularjs 2 and i want it should be only MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, angular-date-format

Here is my line of code from the angularjs Kendo UI grid.

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="createdAt" title="Created Date" width="250" filter="date"></kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the date filter with ng-template

```
<kendo-grid-column field="createdAt" title="Created Date" width="250" >
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{dataItem.DOB | date:ShortDate}}
        </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

and in ts,

```
ShortDate="dd/mm/yyyy"
```